# Documentation content not appearing in Google index

Tags: discussion, documentation, seo

I often find that even minutes after asking a question on the Stack Exchange network, the question will appear on Google when searching something similar. I have yet to find any documentation pages on Google when searching.

To be completely honest, I don't see myself ever using the search box built into Stack Overflow Documentation. I have only ever used the Q&A search box once or twice. Google is how I find almost all of my Stack Overflow Q&A, so without SEO, Documentation would become ultimately useless to me.

Is the Documentation section of Stack Overflow not optimized for search engines like Google, or am I the only one not finding anything?

Comment: Answers are supposed to link to documents, and Q&As are already SEO optimized.

Comment: Makes sense, but I feel like it would be beneficial if the entire Documentation section was also SEO optimized. Imagine searching "How to create arrays in Java," and "Creating Arrays - Java" appeared at the top from documentation. (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays/404/creating-arrays#t=201607230629232605299) It'd be pretty helpful if I was a beginner.

Comment: It took a fat year before Google started to rank SO content.  It did have rather a lot of "hello world" style Q+A in its first year as well :)  Why it would ever prefer SO/doc over oracle.com when somebody queries "how to create arrays in java" is murky, pretty doubtful it ever will.  This kind of content gets added because there is always somebody that thinks it should be there, not because it needs to be there.  No different from Q+A.

Comment: Why would you expect  a 2 day old resource full of hello world to jump to the top of search indexing already?

Comment: I see no progress. It doesn't appear in the search results even after a month.

Comment: It is not "simply" an SEO issue.  If you pick a typical documentation example, and then do a google phrase search for the example's title, you get zero hits.